# Selecting from clobs

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to select data from a clob using DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR() but I'm getting the error

> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too
>   small

I'm using this as I need to rebuild files using snippets from inside clobs and I use the SUBSTR feature to build this.

I'm using the below, note that this works for files where smaller amounts of data are selected but fails when they're seemingly too large:

```
DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(RAW_CLOB,INSTR(RAW_CLOB,'ZPT|',INSTR(RAW_CLOB,(dbms_lob.substr(raw_clob, 4,instr(raw_clob,CHR(10))+1))||'1591018726313')+1)-INSTR(RAW_CLOB,(dbms_lob.substr(raw_clob, 4,instr(raw_clob,CHR(10))+1))||'1591018726313')-1,INSTR(RAW_CLOB,(dbms_lob.substr(raw_clob, 4,instr(raw_clob,CHR(10))+1))||'1591018726313')) file_body
```

which translates to the following when I get values from the INSTR

```
SELECT DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(RAW_CLOB,1000,63) file_body
```

Just running alone, outside of any PLSQL procedure still produces the error. When I shorten the extent to the below I manage to get some results but this is only to provide an example:

```
SELECT DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(RAW_CLOB,4052,63) file_body
```

Comment: How exactly do you do that? Which parameters did you use with the SUBSTR function? What happens if you *shorten* it a little bit (for example, don't select 4000 but 3500 characters) which might be an issue if there are special characters you're selecting. Also, although DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR should be used with CLOBs, try just SUBSTR (I'm not saying that it *will* help, but - it might).

Comment: That error usually means you're trying to store results that are too long for the thing you're trying to store it in. What's the definition of the variable/column you're trying to store the result of that dbms_lob.substr call?

Comment: Question updated

Comment: You  can rule out the problem with special characters (multi-byte characters) by using the SUBSTRB function instead of SUBSTR. That substrings the number of bytes instead of characters.

Comment: I don't think it's an issue with special characters. It worked when selecting a length of 4000 characters but not 4001. Looks like this is because the function returns VARCHAR2(4000). Now I'm not sure what to do about extracting > 4000 characters

Comment: Simply don't. Find out how much you need to extract, then extract multiple pieces. The code will be messy but should work. You can combine the pieces into a clob. If you are on Oracle 12c you could perhaps use 32k instead, see https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/extended-data-types-12cR1. Perhaps that is enough? Requires ALTER SYSTEM SET max_string_size=extended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you're doing this in PL/SQL, but didn't show any PL/SQL so some of this is guesswork.

That error happens when you are selecting into a variable that is too small for your selection. `DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR` returns a `VARCHAR2`, which has a maximum length of 4000 *bytes* in SQL (by default, extensible to 32767) and 32767 *bytes* in PL/SQL. I emphasize bytes there because that can be relevant if you are working in a database with a multibyte character set like AL32UTF8.

Even if you weren't hitting the absolute max limit, you can still get that error if the variable you are selecting `INTO` is too small:

```
declare
    v    varchar2(10 char);
begin
    select dbms_lob.substr( '12345678901', 11, 1 ) into v from dual;
end;
```

If you're going to manipulate large `CLOBs` and break them into pieces, which means always going through an intermediate `VARCHAR2`, you must account for this. Usually, this means breaking up the `CLOB` into chunks of manageable size.

Comment: Just to avoid confusion for people viewing this question, I meant to remove the PL/SQL tag when I updated the question (which has now been updated). The error returns if running in PL/SQL or regular SQL.

Comment: I honestly don't understand how you can be getting this error with 1000 characters. Can you provide a working example?